# How does validation_data affect learning in Keras?

Tags: validation, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

`validation_data` can be passed to `model.fit`, but how does this parameter affect training, and how to confirm optimized parameters of `validation_data`?
I know `validation dataset` is used for models to tune optimal parameters. But I cannot imagine the difference between with and without `validation_data`.

Is e.g. the learning rate of back-propagation is automatically optimized by the validation dataset?

I have read the following
[What is the difference between test set and validation set?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19048/what-is-the-difference-between-test-set-and-validation-set)

> Validation set: a set of examples used to tune the parameters of a
>   classifier. In the MLP case, we would use the validation set to find
>   the "optimal" number of hidden units or determine a stopping point for
>   the back-propagation algorithm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is e.g. the learning rate of back-propagation is automatically optimized by the validation dataset?

No, it is not.

Your model fits the weights of the learned function to your training data using your pre set hyperparameters. That function is validated on your validation set. Based on the performance of your function on the validation set you can set the hyperparameters to good values, either per hand or by using heuristics.

Comment: Thank you. Then, when is validation set validated? I cannot find any validation result during `fit`.

Comment: Normally after every epoch. If you use verbose setting keras outputs the validation score too

Comment: I'll check it later. Then, validation data is just eveluated every epoch. This is exactly same evaluation function as  'evaluate()' on test dataset?